# selectchangedindex giving error in c#.net

Tags: c#

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Sql_type = "select customer_name from tb_customer";

    OleDbCommand cmd_type = new OleDbCommand(Sql_type, con);

    OleDbDataReader DR_two = cmd_type.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable table_one = new DataTable();
    table_one.Load(DR_two);

    DataRow row = table_two.NewRow();
    row["customer_name"] = "Select Poperty Name";

    table_one.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);

    comboBox1.DataSource = table_one;
    comboBox1.DisplayMember = "customer_name";
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "customer_name";
    comboBox1.Text = "Select Poperty Name";
}
```

here from the above code i am fetching customer name from database in a combobox.....now i have another combobox named combobox2 ...nw if a user chooses name from combox1 then the number of that choosen person comes on the second combobox...so i have written the code below for that.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int selectedId = 0;
    if (comboBox1.SelectedValue.GetType() == typeof(DataRowView))
    {
       DataRowView selectedRow = (DataRowView)comboBox1.SelectedValue;
       selectedId = Convert.ToInt32(selectedRow["customer_name"].ToString());
    } else {
      selectedId = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue);
    }

    string Sql2 = "SELECT number FROM table2 WHERE type_id = " + selectedId;

    OleDbCommand cmd_type = new OleDbCommand(Sql2, con);

    OleDbDataReader DR_two = cmd_type.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable table_two = new DataTable();
    table_two.Load(DR_two);

    DataRow row_two = table_two.NewRow();
    row_two["name"] = "Select Number";
    row_two["id"] = 0;
    table_two.Rows.InsertAt(row_two, 0);

    comboBox2.DataSource = table_two;
    comboBox2.DisplayMember = "number";
    comboBox2.ValueMember = "number";
    comboBox2.Text = "Select Number";
}
```

but here Convert.ToInt32 this thing is giving problem..the datatype of number in database is text...but when i remove this it shows error...so what can be done for this??

Comment: Use `comboBox1.Text` to get currently selected text from `ComboBox`.

Comment: it is fetching that but giving prob. in showing no

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to convert the name to an integer here ?

```
Convert.ToInt32(selectedRow["customer_name"].ToString())
```

According to this:

```
string Sql2 = "SELECT number FROM table2 WHERE type_id = " + selectedId;
```

you need a type_id. When you populate the first combo, make sure you have in the Value the required data that you want to you want to use in the above query.

I think in the second query you actually want to have a WHERE by customer_id or something.

To sum it all up:

```
 // change this in the first method:
 string Sql_type = "select customer_name, customer_id from tb_customer";
 comboBox1.ValueMember = "customer_id";

// change this in the second method:
string Sql2 = "SELECT number FROM table2 WHERE customer_id = " + (int)comboBox1.SelectedValue;
```

Adjust the code to match the column names from your application (customer_id might not be the name that you use in both tables)

Comment: here i would like to tell you that no value is in integer and i want all values in string but i dont know how to edit the code...so could you please help?

Comment: If in table2 you don't have the customer_name column, then you need to use the column that makes the link between tables in order to be able to select the phone numbers. What is the name of the column in table2 that identifies the customer ?

Comment: actually the data of both comboboxes is coming from same table

Comment: Your code says otherwise. Please update your question with the existing code because the query in the second method of the current version doesn't really makes sense. Also, if you post the table columns will let us help you easier.